# Invalid END Header Error within my POM file - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am new to eclipse java and I am having an issue with my POM file and would like guidance in knowing how to deal with this error I am obtaining.

I have an error that seems to be pointing to the the maven compiler plugin and I am not sure what is the best approach to fix the following error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Cannot read lifecycle mapping
>   metadata for artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:maven-plugin:3.2:runtime
>   Cause: invalid END header (bad central directory
>   offset)   pom.xml /StudentApp line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle
>   Mapping Problem

Below is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>StudentApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>StudentApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>StudentApp Serenity BDD</name>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>1.4.1-rc.6</serenity.version> <!-- https://bintray.com/serenity/maven/serenity-core/ -->
        <serenity.maven.version>1.4.1-rc.6</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.1.6</serenity.cucumber.version> <!-- https://bintray.com/serenity/maven/serenity-cucumber/ -->
    </properties>

    <!-- Define the Bintray repos for convenience -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>serenity</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/serenity/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>serenity</id>
            <name>bintray-plugins</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/serenity/maven</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireUpperBoundDeps />
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/studentapp/**/*.java</include>
                        <include>**/studentapp/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <!-- <parallel>methods</parallel>  -->
                    <!-- <threadCount>10</threadCount>   --> 
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 
</project>
```

Comment: There is two way 1 - add compiler plugin explicitly, Or 2- delete you .m2 repo compiler plugin dependency and rerun build using mvn install -U command hope this would help you

Comment: Hi afgan, sorry been at work. Just to make sure I have this right, if I went with option 1, do I just go into the maven repository and search for the maven compiler plugin and copy and paste the dependency from there into my Pom file and update my project?

Comment: yes - you  need to add compiler plugin, in build section of your pom.xml see this ->  [comiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html)  -  is suggested solution work for you ?